# JavaScript issue with global variable assignment

Tags: javascript, html, api, geolocation

I'm trying to create a weather widget using below code snippets. However, the global variables longitude and latitude values are not getting updated in the success function. I have tried all the combinations of globalThis and window objects but yet not been able to resolve the issue.

```js
setInterval(showWeather, 900000);
setTimeout(showWeather,1000)

function showWeather(){
    var appid = "API_KEY_FOR_OPENWEATHERMAP";
    var latitude = 0;
    var longitude = 0;
        
    function success(position){
        window.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        window.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    }

    function error(){
        console.log('Some error occurred while retrieving your device location! Hence showing the default location weather!')
    }

    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }else{
        console.log("Your device doesn't support geolcation tracking! Hence showing the default location weather!")
    }
    
    async function fetchWeather(){
        var url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${window.latitude}&lon=${window.longitude}&appid=${appid}&units=metric`
        const response = await fetch(url);
        data = response.json();
        return data
    }

    fetchWeather().then(response=>{
        const icon = response.weather[0].icon;
        document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = response.name;
        document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = response.main.temp + "&deg;";
        url = `https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${icon}.png`;
        document.getElementById("wicon").src = url;
    })
}
```

```html
<h5 id="city">User Location</h5>
<div>
  <img id="wicon" src="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/01d.png" alt="Weather icon">
  <strong id="temp">Temperature&deg;</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have local variables `latitude` and `longitude` that you don't use? That confused me at first.

Comment: I wanted to show default location details even if there are some errors. Due to which I've decided to declare global variables with default values and fetchWeather function should be called irrespective of any error to show default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous, but you're not waiting for it to finish before using the results. You should call `fetchWeather()` from the `success()` function, since that's called when `getCurrentPosition()` finishes.

There's no need to use global variables for `latitude` and `longitude`. Pass them as arguments to `fetchWeather()`.

```js
setInterval(showWeather, 900000);
setTimeout(showWeather, 1000)

function showWeather() {
  var appid = "API_KEY_FOR_OPENWEATHERMAP";

  function success(position) {
    let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    fetchWeather(latitude, longitude).then(response => {
      const icon = response.weather[0].icon;
      document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = response.name;
      document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = response.main.temp + "&deg;";
      url = `https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${icon}.png`;
      document.getElementById("wicon").src = url;
    })
  }

  function error() {
    console.log('Some error occurred while retrieving your device location! Hence showing the default location weather!')
  }

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  } else {
    console.log("Your device doesn't support geolcation tracking! Hence showing the default location weather!")
  }

  async function fetchWeather(latitude, longitude) {
    var url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${appid}&units=metric`
    const response = await fetch(url);
    data = response.json();
    return data
  }
}
```

```html
<h5 id="city">User Location</h5>
<div>
  <img id="wicon" src="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/01d.png" alt="Weather icon">
  <strong id="temp">Temperature&deg;</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Im asking for the curious, **"but you're not waiting for it to finish before using the results"**, But here he passes it as a call back right?

Comment: `success` is the callback, but `fetchWeather` is not.

Comment: Is there a way to show default location details irrespective of any error or exception?

Comment: You could call `fetchWeather()` with default locations from the `error()` function.

Comment: I wrapped the fetchWeather() function inside another function, then making calls using the outer function, and it working with the default global values